# Correcting a Illegal String Offset warning in WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am receiving this error 
"Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in contact-me.php on line 250

Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in contact-me.php on line 252"

and I realized this section of code in the file is wrong, however I'm not quite adept in PHP yet and I am wondering if someone can help me re-write this section to eliminate the error. Thanks! (the error starts on line 250 which begins with $width below and also line 252 which begins with $title).

I tried implementing some of the corrections on other threads but was unsuccessful. I appreciate your assistance.

```
function shortcode_handler($_atts) {
    if ($this->check_settings() === true) {
        $width = intval($_atts["width"]);
        if ($width < 100 || $width > 1000) $width = "";
        $title = $_atts["title"];
        if (empty($title)) $title = htmlspecialchars($this->options['form_title'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $suffix = "_".rand(1000, 9999);
        $form = '
```

I solved it.
I used the following code:

```
if (isset($_atts["width"]))
        $width = var_dump($_atts["width"]);           
  if (isset($_atts["title"])) 
        $title = var_dump($_atts["title"]);
```

Comment: You should add an answer yourself and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SLoW. I posted an answer, but based on my reading, I have to wait 48 hours to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
if (isset($_atts["width"]))
    $width = var_dump($_atts["width"]);           
if (isset($_atts["title"])) 
    $title = var_dump($_atts["title"]);
```